# Error ignored by all browser but Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a **statement** in my code **which was** essentially **wrong**:

```
$(".class:not(.another-class-named-" + name).doSomething();
```

As you can see I wasn't **closing the bracket of the `:not` selector**.

But the only browser which complained about my error was **Safari on iOS**.

Why are all other browser ignoring this error? Respectively why isn't Safari?

Comment: perhaps jQuery does things differently on different browsers in such a way that it allows malformed css selectors in most browsers - so the browsers are not ignoring the error, jQuery is

Comment: I guess this is relative as how browsers handle invalid selector passed to `document.querySelectorAll()` and has nothing to do with jQuery. Can you confirm/infirm it?